# how can I display knitR markdown in a pandoc rendered pdf

Tags: knitr, pandoc

I wish to show the knitR code in the final PDF together with its execution result.
I did not find yet a working way to fence "tripple-backticks"{r}..."tripple-backticks" blocks in the knitR code and see them as-is in the final PDF. 
The backticks get interpreted whatever I do.
This is for tutorial purpose so that people see how to write knitR markdown. The use of html "pre" tags around the block of code leads to removal of the code.

for instance I wish to see this example fully first and then the result thereof
adding 4 spaces before each line like here does not work in RStudio and knit HTML fails

````
```{r test-haskell, engine='haskell', engine.path='ghc', cache=TRUE}
[x | x <- [1..10], odd x]
```
````

**follow-up addition**

I include here some RStudio Rmd code that leads to unexpected PDF content

[image: code in RStudio]

in the pdf, the pre-code block simply disappeared.

[image: pdf result fro above code]

The only fix I found is to invent a fake tag 'rmd' to fence the pieces of markdown I wish to keep as-is. I suspect this is a pandoc issue rather than knitr, unless there is a better way to fence code in knitr. The code I wish to keep can be any of bash, perl, R, or any other manguage used to process the data in the knitr tutorial.

my pandoc command was:

> pandoc --variable=geometry:'top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm,
>   right=1cm' --variable=papersize:'a4paper' --number-sections
>   --table-of-contents --template=default.latex --highlight-style tango testrmd.md -o testrmd.pdf

Can it come from the template I used (default.latex)? It is the only template I found that meets my needs for vignette-like output. Same about 'tango' which is the only coloring scheme that shows some light background in code blocks.

As you see from the screenshots above I am a new-bee here (both in markdown and latex). Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show the example of the code that doesn't work? I'm not sure yet what is wrong with it.

Comment: [does this help?](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pretty/), or perhaps [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knitr/DTTYdjwqrQ8)?

Comment: Thanks (all), I finally made it to install a recent version of pandoc and additional laTex apps on my mac. I also got more links from YiHui to relevant github examples that helped too and I can now produce nice PDF versions from my RStudio markdown contents.